# Why wont my code open multiple files vba

Tags: vba, excel, loops, filesystemobject

I have a code that is supposed to open all the files called "effect00*" in a file path however it only ever opens the first file it finds but I want it to open them all does anyone know why my code wont do this?

My code is:

```
Sub LoopSubfoldersAndFiles()
Dim fso As Object
Dim Folder As Object
Dim subfolders As Object
Dim MyFile As String
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim CurrFile As Object

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
End With

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set Folder = fso.GetFolder("\\My Documents\Output files\analysis-tool-development")
Set subfolders = Folder.subfolders
MyFile = "effect00*.dat"

For Each subfolders In subfolders

Set CurrFile = subfolders.Files

    For Each CurrFile In CurrFile
        If CurrFile.Name Like MyFile Then
            Set wb = Workbooks.Open(subfolders.Path & "\" & MyFile)
        End If
    Next

Next

Set fso = Nothing
Set Folder = Nothing
Set subfolders = Nothing

With Application
    .EnableEvents = True
    .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With
```

End Sub

Comment: You have assigned too many meanings to the word `subfolders` which is both a single subfolder and the subfolder collection. Try to avoid variable names which VBA is using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's lots of over-`Set`ting going on here, it makes for easier reading but is mostly unnecessary. For instance, as you don't use your `Folder` object other than to then get the Subfolders, instead of:

```
Set Folder = fso.GetFolder("\\My Documents\Output files\analysis-tool-development")
Set subfolders = Folder.subfolders
```

You could just:

```
Set subfolders = fso.GetFolder("\\My Documents\Output files\analysis-tool-development").subfolders
```

But assuming you want to keep it easy to read etc., I've gone through the code and relabeled your objects etc. to a) differentiate between vba specific wording and b) identify parent/child like ownership:

```
Sub LoopSubfoldersAndFiles()
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim myTopFolder As Object
    Dim mySubFolders As Object
    Dim mySingleFolder As Object
    Dim myFileCollection As Object
    Dim mySingleFile As Object
    Dim myFilePattern As String
    Dim wb As Workbook

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    End With

    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set myTopFolder = fso.GetFolder("\\My Documents\Output files\analysis-tool-development")
    Set mySubFolders = myTopFolder.subfolders
    myFilePattern = "effect00*.dat"

    For Each mySingleFolder In mySubFolders

    Set myFileCollection = mySingleFolder.Files

        For Each mySingleFile In myFileCollection
            If mySingleFile.Name Like myFilePattern Then
                Set wb = Workbooks.Open(mySingleFolder.Path & "\" & mySingleFile.Name)
            End If
        Next

    Next

    Set fso = Nothing
    Set myTopFolder = Nothing
    Set mySubFolders = Nothing
    Set mySubFolders = Nothing
    Set mySingleFolder = Nothing
    Set myFileCollection = Nothing
    Set mySingleFile = Nothing

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = True
        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With
End Sub
```

Lastly, I've left them in but there is a block of `Set xxx = Nothing` which many would argue is not necessary. It looks neat/tidy but I remember reading somewhere that `End Sub` will clear these out anyway.

Answer (score 0):

See your statement:

```
:
For Each subfolders In subfolders
:
```

Obviously, there is one and only one object `subfolders` in `subfolders`.

As Variatus suggest, try to exercise a better naming policy for your variables.

Comment: Same for `For Each CurrFile In CurrFile`